# Project not loading a library when imported into Chrome+Codio

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, web-ide, codio

I just migrated a [working JSfiddle project](http://jsfiddle.net/hugolpz/xp5vb/28/show/) to Chrome+Codio. I did an [exact copy-paste](https://d.codio.com/hugolpz/Censorship-zh/App/index.html). It failed with the error message:

```
<p>[blocked] The page at <a href="https://d.codio.com/hugolpz/Censorship-zh/App/index.html">https://d.codio.com/hugolpz/Censorship-zh/App/index.html</a> ran insecure content from <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false</a>. 
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined index.html:51 
window.onload</p>
```

It works on JSfiddle (Chrome, Firefox), and Codio with Firefox. It confirms that the JS/HTML/CSS is valid.

It doesn't work on "Chrome + Codio.com". The Google map API link is ok on fiddle.net, but flagged "insecure".

What is the source of this Chrome-Codio failure?

[3]: [except chinese characters addresses but it doesn't matter right now]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Explanation:** This issue is due to Chrome. When Chrome is on a secure website (**https://**Codio.com), it refuses to call non-secure (**http://**) external resources.

---

**Solution/Workaround 1:** Also, instead of

```
<script src="http://mysite.org"></script> // which is forbidden by Chrome!
```

rather use:

```
<script src="//mysite.org"></script>
```

---

**Solution/Workaround 2:** I've been noticed[1] that Codio projects can be run on both https:// and http:// urls. So if your project get in trouble when run as :

```
https://d.codio.com/myName/myProject/App/
```

switch to no-secure url:

```
http://d.codio.com/myName/myProject/App/
```

And all the external ressources should load fine.

[1]: Big thanks to Joel Moss for this explanation and tips !